# Cant access Children > Children... Element jQuery

Tags: jquery

**HTML**

```
<div class="subNavStrip">
                <table class="navTable" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr class="stripContainer">
                        <td class="subNavStriptTitleContainer" style="width: 100%"><a class="subNavStriptTitle">app</a></td>
                        <td class="btnExpander"><a class="expanderSign">[--]</a></td>
                        <td class="nextPrevContainer"><a class="prev">Prev</a></td>
                        <td><a style="color: gray;">|</a></td>
                        <td class="nextPrevContainer"><a class="next">Next</a></td>
                        <td><div class="scrollup subScrollup"></div></td>
                        <td><div class="subShutter"></div></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".subNavStrip").dblclick(function() {
        var currentArea = $(this).parents(".subContainer").children(".expanderArea");
        currentArea.slideToggle("800", "easeOutCubic");
        var sign = $(this).children(".navTable").children(".stripContainer").children(".btnExpander").children(".expanderSign").text();
        if (sign == "[+]") $(this).children(".expanderSign").text("[--]");
        else $(this).children(".expanderSign").text("[+]");
    });
```

Cant get the value of children to the children... element in var 'sign' (4th query line)

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.stripContainer` is not chidren of `.navTable`

as browser add `tbody` tag in `table` so this don't work.

```
var sign = $(this).children(".navTable").children(".stripContainer");
```

---

Try [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
var sign = $(this).find(".expanderSign").text();
```

Comment: than it worked but, can you explain why .stripContainer is not chidren of .navTable?

Comment: @Faizan `tbody` tag inserted by browser after `table` tag before `tr ` see using inspect element in chrome

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because the DOM is kindly inserting a tbody between the table and the tr:

[image]

So the tr is not a child, but a grandchild.